# Convex union operation in R

Tags: r, union

I have 3 vectors

```
a = c(3,7) 
b = c(4,6)
c = c(2,6)
```

I would like to make the union of these 3 sets. I could use the `union()` function but "convex" union requires that the vector `c` is removed from the union because it is dominated by a, which is higher for the two elements.

Any idea of a simple way to do it?

Comment: Can you please post your desired output?

Comment: the output should be a two rows matrix or dataframe containing a and b

Comment: to reformulate the problem, I need to keep the sets which contain any of the ```pmax``` of entire data set

Comment: That reformulation is a different problem, e.g. `d = c(3.5, 6.5)` contains no `pmax`, but is not dominated by either `a` or `b`.

Comment: Indeed, how can I also include it into my union then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each row of `m` is a pair then `which.nondominated(-t(m))` gives the row numbers of the rows not dominated by some other row. The code is written in C so it should be fast.

```
library(ecr)
m <- rbind(a, b, c) # input data

ix <- which.nondominated(-t(m))    # 1, 2
mm <- m[ix, ]
mm
##   [,1] [,2]
## a    3    7
## b    4    6
```

There are no duplicates in this example but if there could be and if you also wanted to remove them then:

```
unique(mm)
```

or

```
mm[!duplicated(mm), ]
```

Comment: Thank you! And what if each row contains 5 elements?

Comment: `?which.nondominated`

Comment: Thanks to your help, I have been able to write this : ```mm = m %>% slice(which.nondominated(-t(.))) %>% distinct()```. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This will work in the cases mentioned above in the comments.

```
a = c(3,7) 
b = c(4,6)
c = c(2,6)
d = c(3.5,6.5)

my_fun <- function(A){
  B <- matrix(NA,ncol=ncol(A))
  for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
    include <- !any(apply(A[-i,],1,function(x){all(A[i,] < x)}))
    if(include){
      B <- rbind(B,A[i,])
    }
  }
  na.omit(B)
}

A <- rbind(a,b,c,d)
my_fun(A)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  3.0  7.0
[2,]  4.0  6.0
[3,]  3.5  6.5
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. As it will be repeated many times in an algorithm, is there a faster way to do it, and preferably without using loops?

Comment: @Simon - you're welcome. How large are you scaling this? I made it a function so it's easier for you to use repetitively. It can also accommodate larger matrices.

Comment: I will repeat this 28528 times for the first iteration of the algo, and it will go up

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to do this without iterating through each vector. You can replace the for-loop with something from the apply family, but that's really just a wrapper for a for-loop. Not sure it's able to be vectorized in any way. Good luck!

Comment: would it be possible to select the rows containing the pmax of the data set, then, if any, salect the rows containing pmax between those 2 rows and continue until all relevant values are selected?

Comment: What you're describing in this scenario would exclude the row (3.5, 6.5). Please spend some time formulating your question and coming up with an example that contains all possible scenarios and what you'd expect the answer to be.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution by [@G. Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59231361/12158757) is so far the best. Here is another solution with `base R`.

Assuming you are using a data frame `df` which consists of `a`,`b`,`c` and `d`, i.e,

```
a = c(3,7) 
b = c(4,6)
c = c(2,6)
d = c(3.5,6.5)

df <- data.frame(t(data.frame(a,b,c,d)))
> df
   X1  X2
a 3.0 7.0
b 4.0 6.0
c 2.0 6.0
d 3.5 6.5
```

then maybe the following code can help you to make convex union

```
l <- combn(df[,1],2,diff)
b <- combn(df[,2],2,diff)
idx <- combn(seq(nrow(df)),2)
m <- df[unique(as.vector(idx[,l*b<0])),]

> m
   X1  X2
a 3.0 7.0
b 4.0 6.0
d 3.5 6.5
```